# How to split the producing XLS sheet to look like the template shown in apache.poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am using **apache poi**

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

.......
.......
```

And then I do the rest of my code. My data is looking good. **But my rows are too long.**
So the client want us to split the sheet into pages as shown in the template below.

How do I achieve this in a **HSSFGWorkbook**?

I tried several things like:

```
sheet.setAutobreaks(true);

sheet.setFitToPage(true);
```

etc.

**Nothing worked.**

I **want the user to see the XLS sheet on screen in the format shown in the template below.**

[image]

As you can see the pages are splitted from left to right.

Here is everything I am trying to in detail. Currently with the code I have written, I create the XLS all dynamically. I do not use any templates etc. So with the current code I have (shown below) I create the following.

[image]

As you can see, my data rows are all in one page in the sheet.
What I need to do is to create the date as shown in the first image I published where you can see pages are split from left to right.

Here is the full code I am using....

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;  

public class XlsxMaker 
{         
    public static void Main (String [] args)
    {
     List<String> columnModelList = ArrayList<String>;
     List<ArrayList<String>> dataList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>;
     String outXlsxFileName = "outXlsFile.xlsx");
       
     //Add the test column names
     columnModelList.add("Col1"); columnModelList.add("Col2");
     columnModelList.add("Col3"); columnModelList.add("Col4");
     columnModelList.add("Col5"); columnModelList.add("Col6");
     columnModelList.add("Col7"); columnModelList.add("Col8");
     columnModelList.add("Col9"); columnModelList.add("Col10");
     columnModelList.add("Col11"); columnModelList.add("Col12");
     columnModelList.add("Col13"); columnModelList.add("Col14");
     columnModelList.add("Col15"); columnModelList.add("Col16");
     columnModelList.add("Col17"); columnModelList.add("Col18");
     columnModelList.add("Col19"); columnModelList.add("Col20");
     columnModelList.add("Col21"); columnModelList.add("Col22");
       
       
     //Add the test data rows
     ArrayList<String> realData = new ArrayList<String>();

     realData.add("Data-1-01"); realData.add("Data-1-02");
     realData.add("Data-1-03"); realData.add("Data-1-04");
     realData.add("Data-1-05"); realData.add("Data-1-06");
     realData.add("Data-1-07"); realData.add("Data-1-08");
     realData.add("Data-1-09"); realData.add("Data-1-10");
     realData.add("Data-1-11"); realData.add("Data-1-12");
     realData.add("Data-1-13"); realData.add("Data-1-14");
     realData.add("Data-1-15"); realData.add("Data-1-16");
     realData.add("Data-1-17"); realData.add("Data-1-18"); 
     realData.add("Data-1-19"); realData.add("Data-1-20");
     realData.add("Data-1-21"); realData.add("Data-1-22");
      
     dataList.add(realData);
      
     realData = new ArrayList<String>();

     realData.add("Data-2-01"); realData.add("Data-2-02");
     realData.add("Data-2-03"); realData.add("Data-2-04");
     realData.add("Data-2-05"); realData.add("Data-2-06");
     realData.add("Data-2-07"); realData.add("Data-2-08");
     realData.add("Data-2-09"); realData.add("Data-2-10");
     realData.add("Data-2-11"); realData.add("Data-2-12");
     realData.add("Data-2-13"); realData.add("Data-2-14");
     realData.add("Data-2-15"); realData.add("Data-2-16");
     realData.add("Data-2-17"); realData.add("Data-2-18"); 
     realData.add("Data-2-19"); realData.add("Data-2-20");
     realData.add("Data-2-21"); realData.add("Data-2-22");
      
     dataList.add(realData);

     //Now make the XLS
     ByteArrayOutputStream baou =  combineXlsComponents(columnModelList, dataList);
     try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outXlsxFileName)) {
        baou.writeTo(outputStream);
     }
    }     
      
      private static ByteArrayOutputStream combineXlsComponents(List<String> columnsList, List<ArrayList<String>> dataList)
      {
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      
       try(HSSFWorkbook workbook = populateXlsData(dataList, prepareColomnHeaders(columnsList))){
            
            workbook.write(baos);
       }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("combineXlsComponents: "+e.getMessage());
        }
            
        return baos;
      }
   
    private static HSSFWorkbook  prepareColomnHeaders(List<String> columnsList) throws IOException
    { 
          HSSFWorkbook  workbook = new HSSFWorkbook ();
      
          Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
            
          /*This block try to put all in one page while printing */
          sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
          sheet.setFitToPage(true);
          sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitHeight((short)0);
          sheet.getPrintSetup().setFitWidth((short)1);
          
          sheet.setColumnBreak(6);
            
          /*Freeze Scrolling first 2 rows */
          sheet.createFreezePane(0,2);    
            
          /*Mergers the row 0 up to column 21 */
          sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,0,0,21));  
             
          Row row0 = sheet.createRow(0);
          row0.setHeightInPoints(23);
          Cell cell1 = row0.createCell(0);
          cell1.setCellValue("For Official Use Only.");
          
          /* Style top privacy act row(0) */
          cell1.setCellStyle(styleFouoRow(workbook));
            
          /* -----------------Styling All other headers  ------------------------*/
          Font boldFont = workbook.createFont();
          boldFont.setBold(true); 
          CellStyle styleForHeaders = workbook.createCellStyle();     
          styleForHeaders.setFont(boldFont); 
          styleForHeaders.setWrapText(true);  
          styleForHeaders.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            
          /*Set the colors for header cells */
          styleForHeaders.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.DARK_BLUE.getIndex()); 
          styleForHeaders.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);       
          styleForHeaders.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.DARK_BLUE.getIndex());  
            
          /*Set the borders for header cells */
          styleForHeaders.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
          styleForHeaders.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            
          styleForHeaders.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
          styleForHeaders.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            
          styleForHeaders.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
          styleForHeaders.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            
          styleForHeaders.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
          styleForHeaders.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            
          HSSFFont fontHeaders = workbook.createFont(); 
          fontHeaders.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
          fontHeaders.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
          fontHeaders.setBold(true);
          styleForHeaders.setFont(fontHeaders);
      
          Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
          row.setHeightInPoints(25);          
            
          int nextCell = -1;
          for (String strObj: columnsList) 
          {  
            Cell cell = row.createCell(++nextCell);
            cell.setCellValue(strObj);
            cell.setCellStyle(styleForHeaders);
          }
            
        /*Set column widths */
          for(int i = 0; i <= 21; i++){
            sheet.setColumnWidth(i, 6000); 
          }
            
          return workbook;  
      }
  
    private static HSSFWorkbook populateXlsData(List<ArrayList<String>> dataList, HSSFWorkbook workbook)
    {
      try 
     {
            if (dataList != null) 
            {
             Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             
             /* First two rows (0 and 1) are already used for the titles and the headers.   
                So data starts in row 2 */
               int rowNum = 2;
                
               CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
               style.setWrapText(true); 
               style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
               
               /* Cycle thru the ROWs and write them to the workbook */
               for (ArrayList<String> dataRow : dataList) 
               { 
                   if (dataRow != null) 
                   {
                    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                    
                    int nextCell = -1;
                    /*Cycle thru each value in each row */
                    for (String nextString : dataRow){
                      Cell cell = row.createCell(++nextCell);
                          cell.setCellValue(nextString);
                          cell.setCellStyle(style);
                    }
                  }
               } 
               
               /*Add the final FOUO */
               sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNum,rowNum,0,21));
               Row lastRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
               lastRow.setHeightInPoints(23);
               Cell cell1 = lastRow.createCell(0);
               cell1.setCellValue("For Official Use Only.");
               /* Style top privacy act row(rowNum) */
               cell1.setCellStyle(styleFouoRow(workbook));
            }
        }catch (Exception exp){
        throw exp;
      }
   return workbook; 
 }
 
    
    private static CellStyle styleFouoRow(HSSFWorkbook inWorkBook)
    {
       CellStyle styleForFouoRow = inWorkBook.createCellStyle();
       styleForFouoRow.setWrapText(true);
       styleForFouoRow.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
       styleForFouoRow.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
           
       HSSFFont font = inWorkBook.createFont(); 
       font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
       font.setFontName("Calibri"); 
       styleForFouoRow.setFont(font); 
            
       return styleForFouoRow;    
    }
}
```

Comment: setColumnBreak() does not do anything. Just tested.

Comment: Hi Axel, I have added the full code into the question. You can see I have added setColumnBreak(6) but it did not break.